# Select string from tooltip in RAP

Tags: swt, tooltip, eclipse-rap

In my RAP application I have SWT `Text` and registered tooltip on it `textSourceLink.setToolTipText("E.g.: p7eail/p7eail_SRN1l.pdf");`

On UI when user hover `Text` tooltip is shown.

Is it possible to select text from that shown tooltip and for example copy that inside text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, text from a tooltip cannot be selected in RAP.